# Dropping packets before mangle POSTROUTING

Tags: iptables, tc

In iptables on Linux 3.10, why do packets which have been DROPed by the FORWARD chain of the standard table still appear in the POSTROUTING chain of the mangle table? -- I'm trying to use the standard FORWARD chain to filter and mangle POSTROUTING to mark packets for tc.

Comment: What makes you sure the packets are dropped? What are the rules? Do you see the packets leave the interface (`tcpdump`)?